# django.contrib.auth.logout in Django

Tags: django

I would like to use the logout function from Django but not sure how to use it properly.I have been referring to this Django User Authenication: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ and it reads

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

The confusing part for me is the # Redirect to a success page. How do i redirect it to another page. Should I use HttpResponseRedirect or add additional arguments to logout(request). I am not sure what to do.. Need some guidance.

Comment: For anyone arriving here after migrating to Django 5.0 and facing a `405 Method Not Allowed` error, please note that as of this version, the `LogoutView` (from `django.contrib.auth.views`) no longer accepts `GET` requests (`POST` only). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0) for more details and [here](https://codereviewdoctor.medium.com/3-awesome-django-4-1-changes-1-is-a-logout-deprecation-you-need-to-know-about-1d8166ccbdb2) for the explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the source of the logout method, it should give you a clear idea what's going on. You can add extra arguments to the logout method to handle redirecting, but you can also append after the method for custom behaviour

```
def logout(request, next_page=None,
           template_name='registration/logged_out.html',
           redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Logs out the user and displays 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    auth_logout(request)
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')
    if redirect_to:
        netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]
        # Security check -- don't allow redirection to a different host.
        if not (netloc and netloc != request.get_host()):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    #etc...
```

Comment: did u import this: from django.contrib.auth import logout ? or something else?

Comment: No it's just Django's source code which tells you there's 5 optional arguments you can append to your logout call

Comment: what should i import to get this running? do u know?

Answer (score 24):

Django has a shortcut method called `redirect`. You could use that to redirect like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

Where `home` is the name of a url pattern you defined in `urls.py` like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'blah.views.index', name='home'))
)
```

In the `redirect` call you could use a path as well, like `/` to redirect to the site root, but using named views is much cleaner.

PS: the code posted by @Hedde is from `django.contrib.auth.views` module, `logout` method. If that's what you want to use, you can import it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
```

Answer (score 18):

You don't have to write a view for that, you can just do:

```
(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',{'next_page': '/accounts/login'})
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

Comment: This does not work if you already included all auth urls with `url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

Comment: @RunLoop so what to do to redirect if I've included all auth urls?

Comment: @StefanoMunarini just redirect from within your view e.g. `HttpResponseRedirect('/registration-success/')`

Answer (score 2):

```
urlpatterns =[
path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="post_list.html"), name='logout'),
]
```

write a template_name as above inside it worked for me.Hope it might be useful.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
def logout_user(request):
    # Log out the user.
    # since function cannot be same as django method, esle it will turn into recursive calls
    logout(request)
    # Return to homepage.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registeration:index'))
```

Comment: I had to rename django.contrib.auth.logout method